# Add column to pandas dataframe with partial file name while importing many files

Tags: python, pandas

I use this to make a giant dataframe from many files in a directory:

```
path = r'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\'              
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*"))

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t') for f in all_files)
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

The files in that path have names like

```
AAA.etc.etc.
AAA.etc.etc
BBB.etc.etc.
```

As I import each file, I want to add a column to the dataframe that has `AAA` or `BBB` next to all the rows imported from that file, like this:

```
col1  col2  col3
data1 data2 AAA
data3 data4 AAA
data1 data2 AAA
data3 data4 AAA
data1 data2 BBB
data3 data4 BBB
```

Comment: what is the rule to know whether to put `AAA` or `BBB` ?

Comment: It's the name of the file, as it's imported. As I `.read_csv` for each file, before concatenating, I want to add a column that has the partial filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

def fn_helper(fn):
    df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep='\t')
    p = PureWindowsPath(fn)
    part = p.name.split('.')[0]
    df['col3'] = part
    return df

df_from_each_file = (fn_helper(f) for f in all_files)
...
```

Or as other people are showing with one-liners:

```
(pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t').assign(col3=PureWindowsPath(f).name.split('.')[0]) for f in all_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check with `keys` + `reset_index`

```
key=[PureWindowsPath(i).name.split('.', 1)[0] for i in all_files]
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True,keys=key).reset_index(level=0)
```

Comment: this won't work since each filename has the whole path included in it

Comment: @aws_apprentice check the update , I borrow your `PureWindowsPath`

Comment: @Liquidity check the update , this should slightly faster than the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I usually change the current working directory to the path:

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```

You can assign `col3` to be the part of the filename you wish by using `assign`.

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t').assign(col3=f.split('.')[0]) for f in all_files)
```

So your code would look like:

```
os.chdir(path)
all_files = glob.glob('*')

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f).assign(col3=f.split('.')[0]) for f in all_files)
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

If you don't want to change the current working directory, then you could use `os.path.basename(path)` to get the filenames in the path. so your code would look like:

```
all_files = glob.glob('*')
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f).assign(col3=os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0]) for f in all_files)
concatdf = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Using `f.split('.')` truncates the file, but includes the path before, so the column is `C:\\Users\\me\\data\\AAA` instead of just `AAA`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I usually use `os.chdir(path)` to change the current working directory to the path. I will update my answer a bit.